# Trouble solving these two equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

I'm doing a homework on uniform distribution and they gave me then mean and the standard deviation. I figured I had to solve for a and b to get min and max values.

But when I try to solve for a and b, it ends nowhere near what wikipedia gives me.

$E(X)=\frac{1}{2}(a+b)$

$V(X)=\frac{1}{12}(b-a)^2$

I should end up with

$a=E(X)-\sqrt{3V(X)}$

$b=E(X)+\sqrt{3V(X)}$

Can you show me how to solve these equations ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Moments_and_parameters

Comment: In the first equation, try to write the equation b = (function of expected value and a). Then substitute it into the other should let you write a in terms of expected value and variance. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E(X)^2=\frac{(a+b)^2}{4}$$

$$3V(X)=\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$$

Subtracting gives

$$E(X)^2-3V(X)=ab$$

With $a+b = 2E(X)$, we get $a = 2E(X) - b$

hence

$$E(X)^2-3V(X)=(2E(X)-b)b$$

$$b^2 - 2E(X)b + E(X)^2-3V(X) = 0$$

So $b = \frac{2E(X)+\sqrt{12V(X)}}{2}$

if you choose the solution with + for b

Then the solution with - is a.

Note : You can swap a and b to get the same result

Comment: damn I had found the same value for B but didn't realise $\sqrt{12}/2$ = $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: So you were very near indeed.